# how to upload file to openstack cloud using NSStream?

Tags: ios, openstack, nsstream

I'm trying to upload a large file on `openstack` cloud using their api. Anyone please give me some example of how to upload a large file to http server using `NSStream`.

Thanks

Comment: Did you read manual? http://docs.openstack.org/api/quick-start/content/

Comment: Thanks , yes i m studying this manual. but i m not getting the concept of uploading stream. if u have any sample so please give me a link.

Comment: hi, i m trying to Authenticate request but getting 401 error code. and couldnt identify whats wrong i m doing here. so please give ios Authenticate on openstack api